# Wrong Image path Url using CarrierWave gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

Hello i am using carrievwave gem for uploading images for my rails app which works fine but i am unable to access those uploaded file. i am getting wrong path url   `http://localhost/uploads/gallery/image_name/354340/1.jpg`
(Here '354340' is Userid not autoincremented id )

Current path should be like this `http://doitfornow:3000/uploads/gallery/image_name/2/1.jpg`

**Model**

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image_name, :name, :user_id,:image_name#,:remote_image_name_url
  mount_uploader :image_name, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id"

end
```

**View**

```
<%@gallery.each do |f|  %>
<tr>
    <td class="left"><%= f.Gname%></td>
    <!-- # u.avatar.url -->
    <td class="left"><%= image_tag f.image_name.url , :size => "50x50" %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Detail',"/articles/detail?id="+f.Gid.to_s  %></td>
    <td class="left" colspan="5"><label class="input-control checkbox"><%= check_box_tag 'user_ids[]', f.Gid, false %> <span class="helper"></span></label></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

image_uploder.rb

```
 # encoding: utf-8

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  #  include CarrierWave::jekyll-minimagick


  # Include the Sprockets helpers for Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  # include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  # include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper
  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
 def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
 end


  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
    # # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
    # # process :resize_to_limit => [200, 200]
      # process :resize_to_fill => [50, 50]
   # # process :scale => [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

Comment: Can you post the content of ImageUploader?

Comment: 2 should be your gallery ID, but instead it is your user ID? That right? So if you do something like <%= "Model ID #{f.id}" %> you get Model ID 2? Your image_uploder.rb seems correct. However, is 1.jpg the default filename?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I did it by creating a module for carrierwave, cause I have more uploaders to handle. I override the 'store_dir' method and add 'set_store_dir' method.
So I can store my files where I want. I set the store_dir in the class including the uploader
Hope it helps

```
    module Helper::Carrierwave
        def set_store_dir( dir )
          @storedir = dir
        end

        def store_dir
          @storedir
        end
    end
```